# Can we use $scope in custom services in Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs

I am getting errors in custome service if I use **$scope**, But it works fine with **$rootScope**. Can't we use $scope in custome service

Comment: Please share your code, or we'll not be able to help you at all

Comment: Either you put your code then i'll explain better

Answer (score 0):

```
app.service("myService", function ($rootScope) {
    console.log($rootScope);
    this.root = $rootScope;
});

app.run(function (myService, $rootScope) {
    console.log($rootScope);
    console.log(myService.root);
});
```

You can only get `$rootScope` injected to `services` and `run` function, because each `child scope` is inherited from its parent scope and the top level scope is `rootScope`. Since it would be ambigous to inject *any* scope. Only root scope is provided.

Services are created before controllers, so there is no child scope available to inject.